# Get file size stored (GCP) in a bucket with airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

The context is that I need to end the process if a file, stored in Google Cloud Platform is empty, but if isn´t empty, follow the normal workflow. I´m doing this with a branch operator in airflow, but i have to pass a condition to decide if the process needs to end there, or continue.

So my question is: how can I get the size of a flat file stored in a bucket in GCP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Blobs/Objects](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html) builtin functions inside the Google Cloud Storage Library for Python.

In order to check if a file is inside your bucket and its size is greater than zero, I have created the following code:

```
from google.cloud.storage import Blob
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.bucket('bucket_name')

desired_file = "file_name.csv"

for blob in bucket.list_blobs():
    if desired_file== blob.name and blob.size > 0:
        print("Name: "+ blob.name +" Size blob obj: "+str(blob.size) + "bytes")
        #do something
```

Above, the [list_blobs()](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) method was used to list all the files inside the specified bucket. Then, we used `blob.name` to retrieve the file's name and `blob.size` in order to return the file's size in ***BYTES***. After this small chunk of code you can continue your tasks.

*Additional information: It is also possible to filter the files you will list with a prefix, in case there are a huge amount, such as `for blob in client_bucket.bucket('bucket_name') .list_blobs(prefix='test_'):`*

***UPDATE:***

In order to give more fine grained permissions, regarding specific buckets and objects, you can use [Access Control Lists](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists). It allows you to define access to particular buckets and objects,according to a desired [access level](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions). Thus, go to: *Storage> Bucket> Click on your file> Click on* ***EDIT PERMISSIONS*** (upper mid screen, next to DOWNLOADS)*> Add item*. Then, select the entity you want to add such as : Project, Domain, Group, User, fill in the name (email id, project, service account). [Link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#set-an-acl) for "How to use ACLs" from Google.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

But it gave me an error trying to list_blobs.

The error says "Client' object has no attribute 'list_blobs"

Comment: @Aldo, instead of using `client_bucket.list_blobs(bucket):` just use `bucket.list_blobs()`. I have updated my code and tested again, it worked.

Comment: Thanks! now I just have an error about permissions for list_blobs, your answer is correct and it work, but is there any way to get just one file from bucket instead of list_blobs? I'm asking this because there is just one file that I have to check, and always will be the same name, and I can't change the permissions for that service account.

Thanks and sorry for the delay of my response!

Comment: @Aldo, in this case, you can use [Access Control List](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) to give individual permissions to your buckets and objects. Go to: Storage>Click on your bucket>Click on your file> Click on *EDIT PERMISSIONS( upper mid screen, next to DOWNLOADS)>Add item.* Then select the entity you want to add such as : *Project, Domain, Group, User*, fill in the name (*email id, project, service account*), and finally the [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions).