# Airflow DAG: Moving empty CSV files to archive bucket and inserting non-empty files into BigQuery

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using Airflow for data processing tasks, specifically involving CSV files. I have a requirement where I need to implement a functionality that checks the size of a CSV file in a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket, and based on that, either moves the file to an archive bucket if it's empty (size 0), or inserts its contents into a BigQuery table if it's non-empty.

I'm fairly new to Airflow, so I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve this. I have a basic understanding of Airflow's operators, but I'm not sure which ones would be the best fit for this particular use case.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish in more detail:

- Check the size of a specific CSV file in a GCS bucket.
- If the file size is 0 (empty), move the file to an archive bucket within GCS.
- If the file size is greater than 0, insert the contents of the file into a BigQuery table.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide me with insights on how to set up this workflow in Airflow.

If anyone has any sample code snippets or example DAGs (Directed Acyclic Graphs) that demonstrate a similar workflow, it would be incredibly helpful.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_gcs import GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import datetime
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

# Define the DAG
dag = DAG(
    'csv_to_bigquery',
    description='A simple DAG to load CSV into BigQuery',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 7, 1),
    catchup=False
)

# Detect .csv file in GCS bucket with specific prefix
detect_csv = GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='detect_csv',
    source_bucket='your-source-bucket',
    source_object='prefix/path/to/csv*.csv',  
    destination_bucket='your-archive-bucket',
    destination_object='prefix/archive/path', 
    move_object=True,
    dag=dag
)

# Load .csv file into BigQuery table
load_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='load_bigquery',
    bucket='your-source-bucket',
    source_objects=['prefix/path/to/csv*.csv'], 
    destination_project_dataset_table='your-project.your_dataset.your_table',
    schema_fields=[  # Define your BigQuery table schema here
        {'name': 'column1', 'type': 'STRING'},
        {'name': 'column2', 'type': 'INTEGER'},
        {'name': 'column3', 'type': 'FLOAT'},
    ],
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE', 
    source_format='CSV',
    dag=dag
)

# Move .csv file to archive bucket
move_to_archive = GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='move_to_archive',
    source_bucket='your-source-bucket',
    source_object='prefix/path/to/csv*.csv',  
    destination_bucket='your-archive-bucket',
    destination_object='prefix/archive/path', 
    move_object=True,
    dag=dag
)

# Define task dependencies
detect_csv >> load_bigquery >> move_to_archive
```

Comment: For your workflow, to execute the conditional ie. `if` block you can make use of `branchpython` operator as used here in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74284006/sensor-file-from-gcs-to-bigquery-if-success-load-it-to-gcs-bucket-else-load-it/74313746#74313746). You can then bind your csv file size logic into the code. To get the file size refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603061/get-file-size-stored-gcp-in-a-bucket-with-airflow). Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[astro-sdk-python](https://github.com/astronomer/astro-sdk) has `load_file` operator that allows you to load data from files into your target transformation system. Read more at: [load file documentation](https://astro-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/astro/sql/operators/load_file.html). `load_file` supports checks for empty-files as well.

1. Without native support:

   ```
    aql.load_file(
       input_file=File("s3://path/to/csv_file_name.csv", conn_id=AWS_CONN_ID),
       output_table=Table(conn_id="bigquery", metadata=Metadata(schema="astro")),
       use_native_support=False,
   )
   ```
2. Using native support:

   ```
   aql.load_file(
       input_file=File("s3://path/to/csv_file_name.csv", conn_id=AWS_CONN_ID),
       output_table=Table(conn_id="bigquery", metadata=Metadata(schema="astro")),
       use_native_support=True,
       native_support_kwargs={
           "ignore_unknown_values": True,
           "allow_jagged_rows": True,
           "skip_leading_rows": "1",
       },
   )
   ```